# Did asker get notification for deleted answer?

Tags: discussion, moderators, notifications

I asked this  question 
 [Searching for TV series consisting of Police trio team](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10837/searching-for-tv-series-consisting-of-police-trio-team) which got correct answer (in very bad format) but the answer got deleted by mod the same day (refer answer by Ans) and I didn't got any notification of it. So is this works this way? Did asker doesn't got notification of a answer which got deleted when he is not active?

Comment: I've undeleted it for you. I'm surprised you didn't get any notification of the answer.

Comment: @iandotkelly thanx.